# Multiple query PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I know this is common to ask but I'm newbie in **PHP**, The problem I've encountered is that the multiple `Insert` queries do not work in my current code, it works if I've removed at least one query `Insert` but what if I have multiple queries and `CRUD` it to another table, I just want to combine query when inserting data to different table, Any help can do

```
function signUp($table, $id_no, $middlename, $lastname)
{
    $id_no = $this->prepareData($id_no);
    $middlename = $this->prepareData($middlename);
    $lastname = $this->prepareData($lastname);
    $table2 = "users";
    $userrole = 0;
    $username = "test_username";
    $password = "test_password";

    $this->sql =
        "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (id_no, middle_name, last_name) VALUES ('" . $id_no . "','" . $middlename . "','" . $lastname . "')" ; //IF I removed this first query it will work to second table
        "INSERT INTO " . $table2 . " (user_role, username, password) VALUES ('" . $userrole . "','" . $username . "','" . $password . "')";
    if (mysqli_query($this->connect, $this->sql)) {
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

**Updated**

```
    function userDetailsTable($table, $firstname,$middlename, $lastname, $sex, $id_no,  $email, $contactno, $address)
{
    $firstname = $this->prepareData($firstname);
    $middlename = $this->prepareData($middlename);
    $lastname = $this->prepareData($lastname);
    $sex = $this->prepareData($sex);
    $id_no = $this->prepareData($id_no);
    $email = $this->prepareData($email);
    $contactno = $this->prepareData($contactno);
    $address = $this->prepareData($address);

    $result =sql2("SELECT MAX(id) FROM users");  // returns error
    
    $this->sql =
        "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (user_id,first_name, middle_name, last_name, sex, id_no, email, contact_no, address) VALUES ('" . $result . "','" . $firstname . "','" . $middlename . "','" . $lastname . "','" . $sex . "','" . $id_no . "','" . $email . "','" . $contactno . "','" . $address . "')" ;
    if (mysqli_query($this->connect, $this->sql)) {
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, multiple query doesn't work. So you have to run two queries. As simple as that

Comment: 1) Just call mysqli_query twice - once for each insert. Wrap them in a transaction if you want to be sure they both succeed or both fail. 2) BUT... you should not be building queries in this insecure way anyway. Use prepared statements and parameters, always (and just execute two statements, of course :-) )

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use it again.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords in plain text - that is another security risk. Learn about [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes I tried that but it doesn't work please see my updated code above on how did I implement it, is there something wrong?

Comment: @ADyson I have my updated code  above  I tried creating two sql but still it didn't work, and those are just  dummy data

Comment: Well...you're still only executing one query there. Your code never does anything with $this->sql2!

Comment: And it's still horrendously insecure. Follow the advice above and start using prepared statements and parameters, urgently.

Comment: @ADyson I just read the link above but I didn't understand, should I make two functions separately?

Comment: `should I make two functions separately`...yes, that's what we said in the very first comments. Start by making it run mysqli_query twice - once for each SQL statement. Then move onto reimplementing your queries safely as per the simple examples at https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#prepare

Comment: @ADyson but what if I have two queries, one is `retrieving data` which use **select** and then getting the max id of the data then insert it, I have update code above need help

Comment: If you have two queries to run, then you prepare and execute two statements. It's as simple as that. I have no idea what your updated code is doing - what is the `sql2()` function?

Comment: Please do by this example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62369599/285587